# popup window when searching posts laravel

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, laravel

I'm making a functionality to search for records

**controller**

```
public function search(Request $request)
    {
        $textSearch = $request->get('blog-search');
        $articleSearch = Article::where('title', 'LIKE', '%'.$textSearch.'%')->get();

        return view('blog.search-list', compact('articleSearch'));
    }
```

**route**

```
Route::get('/search', 'App\Http\Controllers\BlogController@search');
```

**search.blade.php**

```
<div class="blog-search">
    <form id="search" action="/blog/" method="get" role="search">
        <input type="text" id="blog-search" name="blog-search" autocomplete="off">
        <div class="blog-search-result" id="blog-search-result"></div>
    </form>
</div>
```

**search-list.blade.php**

```
<?php if ($articleSearch) { ?>
    <div class="list block-shadow">
        <?php foreach ($articleSearch as $article) { ?>
            <a href="<?= $article->getUrl() ?>"><?= $article->title ?></a>
        <?php } ?>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

**js**

```
$(document).on('keyup', '[name="blog-search"]', function () {
  let data = $(this).closest('form').serialize();
  let searchResult = $('#blog-search-result');

  searchResult.html('');

  if ($(this).val().length < 2) {
      return;
  }

  $.ajax({
      url: '/search',
      data: data,
      method: 'get',
      success: function (result) {
          searchResult.html(result.html);
      }
  });
});
```

As a result, the search works and in the network I get this piece of code

[image]

But the problem is that this piece of code should appear in this block `<div class="blog-search-result" id="blog-search-result"></div>`

And I still can't figure out where to do it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got the right idea, but you can't return a `view()` like that if you're expecting to inject it into the DOM as HTML. Use this approach instead:

```php
public function search(Request $request) {
  $textSearch = $request->get('blog-search');
  $articleSearch = Article::where('title', 'LIKE', '%'.$textSearch.'%')->get();

  $html = view('blog.search-list', compact('articleSearch'))->render();

  return response()->json(['html' => $html], 200);
}
```

The `render()` method converts the view to a `string`, which you then pass back as `JSON` via `response()->json()`. Your `AJAX` handler is correct; `searchResult.html(result.html);`

Sidenote, if you're using `.blade.php`, you don't need raw PHP:

```html
@if($articleSearch)
  <div class="list block-shadow">
    @foreach($articleSearch as $article)
      <a href="{{ $article->getUrl() }}"><{{ $article->title }}></a>
    @endforeach
  </div>
@endif
```

`@if()` can replace your `<?php if (...) { ?>`, and `@foreach()` can replace `<?php foreach(...) } ?>` (along with `@endif` and `@endforeach`)

Comment: It worked like this `return response()->json(['html' => $articleSearch]);`, 
where in the response i get `{"html":[{"id":66,"draft":0,"title":"Article 1","slug":"article_1"......` but the problem remained the same, in my block `<div class="blog-search-result" id="blog-search-result"></div>` 
nothing appears until, I can figure out what the problem is

Comment: `$articleSeach` is a `Collection` of `Article` Models, that's not something that you can render with `searchResult.html(result.html);`... `return response()->json(['html' => view('blog.search-list', compact('articleSearch'))->render()], 200);` You need to "render" the `view`, and return that, then `searchResult.html(result.html);` will work.

Comment: And everything seems to be figured out, it works, thanks

Comment: Haha sweet; glad you got it working. Cheers! 